# How to use if condition in load runner to verify web_reg_Save_param() value?

Tags: rest, if-statement, loadrunner, vugen

I am trying to verify `web_reg_Save_param()` value in if condition but not able to verify please provide me the solution and i have used if condition as

```
if(lr_eval_string(Gmessage==Smessage))
    {
        lr_end_transaction("10_GetSecurity_Token",LR_PASS);
    }
    else
    {
        lr_end_transaction("10_GetSecurity_Token",LR_FAIL);
    }
    //lr_end_transaction("10_GetSecurity_Token",LR_AUTO);
    return 0;
```

Where i am getting Gmessage as Success in `web_reg_save_param()`, please help how to verify to check valid and invalid for json response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative/Simple Way:

1. Capture the response(for ex: c_Response=Success)
2. Use below code for validation:

   ```
    if(strcmp(lr_eval_string("{c_response}"),"Success")==0)
       lr_end_transaction(....,LR_PASS);
   else
       lr_end_transaction(....,LR_FAIL);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

## FoundationSkills - Language of your test tool.

I will recommend a book that I own and one which I have recommended to relatives to address this issues, http://www.c-for-dummies.com/

It is a good book.  Easy to follow.  This will address your foundation skills issue in the 'C' programming language.  My copy sits on my shelf among a dozen or more bright yellow "For Dummies...." books

Answer (score 0):

you have to use c string manipulation functions like strcmp or strstr functions.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you have 2 parameters Gmessage and Smessage, you can compare them with lr_checkpoint()

```
lr_checkpoint("StepName=VerifyCheckpoint", 
    "ExpectedValue={Gmessage}", 
     "ActualValue={Smessage}", 
    "Compare=Equals", 
    "StopOnValidationError=true", 
    LAST );
```